# execute "argument" \r (carriage return) doesnt work

Tags: vim

I want to add autocmd to .vimrc with onoremap mapping as follows:

```
augroup Stdin_BeforeNext@

 autocmd!

 autocmd StdinReadPre * onoremap bn@ :<c-u>execute "normal! /@\rhvB"<cr>

augroup END
```

but when I pres for example `cbn@`(change "before next @" - as i just created) in command line it shows `/@` - so it actually finds next "@", but doesn't return, and of course - doesn't complete the rest (visually select a word back, as i want). But neither `\<cr>` works. So how is it possible to NOT work in exe command, where there should both `\<cr>` key and `\r` as "return" work. Hope you understand my mapping (not that difficult).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, your mapping works exactly as expected for me. Can you share more about your environment? What does `:omap bn@` say? What does `:set cpo?` say? Is it possible this is breaking when `@` is the first character on a line?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: I dont know what does cpoptions have to do with my problem, however they are set "cpoptions=aABceFs", and dont think it breaks because of @ would be the first character at the line. Still exe the same: search, and break - doesnt execute the rest. But If you metioned the cpoption - what is that? how can it help me? (i looked at help section, but dont understand)

Comment: Yes, it does work with `\r`, `\n` or `\<lt>CR>`. `\<CR>` results in an error, but that's expected.

Comment: Yeah `cpo` is not the problem. There is `<` in `cpo` which would have affected the `<CR>` in the end, but it's not set in your case. What about `:omap bn@`? Is the mapping being preserved correctly fdom the autocmd? Can you share more details on the text where you're using this mapping and it's failing to do what you'd expect? Can you get the right result if you execute the commands by hand?

Comment: yes, and that is more weird - i can actually select the text by hand /@ then enter the Bvf@. And is selected. I think the problem is with the return, but not sure.

Comment: If you run `:execute "normal! /@\rhvB"` by hand, does that work? How about `:execute "normal! /@\r"`? And `:execute "normal! /something\r"` (for something else that's in your text)?